# Using JavaScript, how do I perform a binary search that will return multiple values?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, nosql

### Background

I currently have an array like this:

`[1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,9,10]`

I have been using a great JS Binary Search formula from [this website](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml):

```
searchArray = function(needle, haystack, case_insensitive) {
    if (typeof(haystack) === 'undefined' || !haystack.length) return -1;
    
    var high = haystack.length - 1;
    var low = 0;
    case_insensitive = (typeof(case_insensitive) === 'undefined' || case_insensitive) ? true:false;
    needle = (case_insensitive) ? needle.toLowerCase():needle;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = parseInt((low + high) / 2)
        element = (case_insensitive) ? haystack[mid].toLowerCase():haystack[mid];
        if (element > needle) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (element < needle) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
};
```

This works fine for returning a single value.

### Question

How do I return a range rather than a single value?  For example, how would I return all values of `8` from the array, but STILL use the binary search (I do not want to loop through everything!!).

Thanks!

Comment: @ManseUK--No worries!  Any ideas?

Comment: working on it !!!!! would the input always be a single number ? (the word range is throwing me)

Comment: @ManseUK--If that is throwing you, feel free to alter.  I am using that particular script for word searches as well, but feel free to simplify.  My best idea so far is to find a positive match and then increment AND decrement outwards to gather all matches but that seems slow and nasty.

Comment: exactly what i was thinking - crashed my browser a few times testing already !!!!

Comment: I am thinking of running the binary search recursively after the first positive result to accomplish the same outcome, but without iterations.  Still sussing out exactly how to do that. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/DCLey/3/

```
var arr = ['1','1','2','3','4','5','5','5','6','7','8','8','8','8','9','10'];
        //  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15            
var searchArray = function(needle, haystack, case_insensitive) {
    if (typeof(haystack) === 'undefined' || !haystack.length) return -1;

    var high = haystack.length - 1;
    var low = 0;
    var vals = []; 
    var bUp = true; 
    var bDown = true;
    var i = 1; 
    case_insensitive = (typeof(case_insensitive) === 'undefined' || case_insensitive) ? true:false;
    needle = (case_insensitive) ? needle.toLowerCase():needle;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = parseInt((low + high) / 2)
        element = (case_insensitive) ? haystack[mid].toLowerCase():haystack[mid];
        if (element > needle) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (element < needle) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            vals.push(mid); 
            while(bUp || bDown){
                if(bUp && haystack[mid] === haystack[mid + i]){
                    vals.push(mid + i); 
                }else{
                    bUp = false;   
                }
                if(bDown && haystack[mid] === haystack[mid - i]){
                    vals.push(mid - i); 
                }else{
                    bDown = false;   
                }
                i++;
            }
            return vals; 
        }
    }

    return -1;
};

alert(searchArray('8', arr, true));
```

Comment: @BrandonBoone--Thanks Brandon, I think this has great potential.  I am taking a look to see if I can build upon your fiddle to use a recursive binary search rather than an incremented loop in the event of an extremely large data set.  If I can suss that out I will forward you the result so that you can update your answer and get credit.  Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Not sure I follow your "recursive" binary search idea. Your input array must be sorted as a requirement of a binary search. Since this is the case, the other matching values are guaranteed to be sequentially above or below the initially found value. So a binary search which seeks to compare values as being > or < (thus reducing the search set) doesn't seem to fit since you've already used it to find the initial start value and any further matches must be sequentially > or < from that starting value's index.

Comment: @BrandonBoone--I realize that it probably sounds weird.  My thinking is that, rather than iterating outwards to find the boundaries, it may be faster (on a very large dataset) to run a recursive binary search to find said boundaries.  So when the first matching `haystack[mid]` is found, you recurse the search using that value as  a the `high` and the low value stays the same.  You do this until you can no longer find the `needle` value and then you should have your first index.  Then you repeat that process for the last index of `needle` using original mid & high.  Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you just want to count the number of instances of a given number, then you need to return the upper and lower indices of the number in the array. We can choose from 2 approaches:

1. Write a binary search that returns the indices of the upper and lower bounds as an array
2. Stick with the standard binary search which returns the lower bound, and then simply iterate up until we reach the end of the run.

Taking approach 2 is slightly less performant, but retains the general algorithm.